# I got a blank page after running "npm run dev" in terminal

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js

I am trying to run this following github project locally.

https://github.com/jas0ncn/resume

However, after finishing `npm install` and `npm run dev`,

it opens a blank page in my chrome. There's no error in the terminal. It said compiled successfully in *4642ms*.

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you on localhost:8080?

Comment: Yes, I am on localhost:8080

Comment: I'm not going to clone and install it, but open an issue with Jason if it's not working.

Comment: clone it again and try same commands again. it works

Comment: Your problem lies with your routes. You did not import `vue-router` into `main.js`. Secondly, you did not have a `<router-view></router-view>` anywhere in your code. Please fix those two first.